# Access queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables in MS-Access, U and R. I have joined them together and want to compare two fields. However, because there are X Tags in both to compare I am getting X lines.  As you can see on ID 4 and 2 there are two tags in each table and they are both the same however because of my query I get four lines back because it compares all combinations. I do have a Unique Values set to yes. How can I make this work only getting back two lines for the below examples.

```
ID  U Tag1   R Tag2  Comp
1   100XX7   100XX7  SAME
2   11646L   11644   DIFFERENT
2   11646L   1X05X   DIFFERENT
2   15650    11644   DIFFERENT
2   15650    1X05X   DIFFERENT
3   5981X    598X0   DIFFERENT
4   19103    19103   SAME
4   19103    19X95   DIFFERENT
4   19X95    19103   DIFFERENT
4   19X95    19X95   SAME
```

Comment: Can you provide the query returning this values? Can you provide the data on the tables used in that query?

Comment: could you provide the desired output you want also? So I can see what you really want

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something on the lines of:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Tag, r.ID, r.Tag
FROM u INNER JOIN r ON (u.ID = r.ID) AND (u.Tag = r.Tag)

UNION ALL

SELECT u.ID, u.Tag, r.ID, r.Tag
FROM u LEFT JOIN r ON (u.ID = r.ID) AND (u.Tag = r.Tag)
WHERE r.Tag Is Null
```

The first part shows matched tags, the second part (after Union All) shows tags in u that were not found in r.

Answer (score 0):

add a

`GROUP BY id, U.Tag1, R.Tag2, (Comp? perhaps if you need that in your output)`

clause to whatever query you're using now :)